# Input range slider animation CSS

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I'd like to see if it's possible to animate the `input[type="range"]` element for example for short audio files so the progress seems less 'stuttery'

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/liamtarpey/pen/gKzjLo?editors=1100) with a short audio file that I've been using to try to come up with solutions

This question is specifically for `input[type="range"]`, I do not want to use custom elements to build animated progress bars, I know that is possible but for this particular use case I'm stuck with the range element.

Any ideas?

[image: Range input lives natively in the shadow root of audio element]

Comment: The slider position depends on the _value_ of the input field - and that value isn’t CSS’ business. // Why you are pointing to a pen with an `audio` element is a mystery to me though. What does that have to do with `input[type="range"]`, _especially_ if you say you don’t want to implement custom controls …?

Comment: @CBroe the reason behind it is that the native HTML audio element uses `input[type="range"]` by default and I'm implementing a well tested library Plyr (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) which just builds on top of the native implementation - therefore forcing me to stick with range input. Have updated the question with a screenshot of the native audio element shadow DOM.

Comment: Well Shadow DOM is the important keyword here … you won’t be able to reach into that with any custom styling from your “parent” document in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, I thought as much - I was just hoping there was a workaround for this, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

As the input handle is a browser element it can not be animated. You would have to build a slider similar to the jQuerUI [one](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) and then animate the handle by updating its position on the range change input.

If you have longer audio files this will not happen (about 1s of audio per pixel)